# BULK INSERT from sql server as a query in python

Tags: python, sql, bulkinsert

I have been struggling with a task as follows:

I have an active connection from my python application with sql server and I would like to perform a bulk insert operation that insert data from a specific file into my database.
When I perform this directly from sql server it works fine but with python I always get the message regarding escape character '/' - it is a Windows machine.

I cannot just figure this out how to get this done: I tried:
a) to replace '/' with '//' but then sql server crushed
b) to create a stored procedure and refer to it in c.execute but it does not work either
c) to replace '/' with '' - then sql cannot open a file
d) to create a varaible with raw string r'' and pass this as a parameter into sql server code but also does not work

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={user};PWD={password}')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''
   BULK INSERT Namen 
   FROM 'C:\Users\pllmkd\Desktop\test.txt'
   WITH (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
''')
c.commit()


c.close()
conn.close()
```

What should be the approach to that problem? I don't want to read a file row by row as I have hundres of thousands row in each file i want to upload.

The error I get:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 36-37: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Could you please suggest a solution?

Thank you in advance for any tips

Comment: If you're doing this on Windows, why not just use BCP?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the \? I.e. `FROM 'C:\\Users\\pllmkd\\Desktop\\test.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\` character is used to define [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#escape-sequences). You need to either escape `\` itself or use a raw string by using the `r` prefix. From the docs:

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters.

The `r` prefix should be applied to the *entire* string, not the path inside the string. Python doesn't parse the contents of the string and doesn't care about the path itself.

You should use

```
sql=r'''
   BULK INSERT Namen 
   FROM 'C:\Users\pllmkd\Desktop\test.txt'
   WITH (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
'''
c.execute(sql)
```

or

```
sql='''
   BULK INSERT Namen 
   FROM 'C:\\Users\\pllmkd\\Desktop\\test.txt'
   WITH (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
'''
```

**Make sure the server account can access the file**

The path passed to BULK INSERT is treated as a local file on the database server, unless it's a path to a shared folder. The file will be accessed using SQL Server's service account, which means that account needs to be given Read permission at least on that file or folder.

`C:\Users\pllmkd\Desktop.txt` is a local path, stored in a user's Desktop, where only that user has access. SQL Server would have to run on the same machine, using the `pllmkd` as the service account. The default SQL Server installation uses a low-privilege account though, not the current user's account.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I pasted exactly your code but this is the error I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\\\\Users\\\\pllmkd\\Desktop\\\\test.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Odmowa dost�pu.). (4861) (SQLExecDirectW)')

looks like it cannot localte the file now when I use r before the sql query

Comment: That's not a code problem or even a Python problem. It's telling you the *server* can't file the file on its local `C:` drive. Either you tried to use a local path on a remote server or the server account doesn't have permission to read from `C:\Users\plmkd`. You'd get the same error if you tried the SQL command in SSMS, Azure Data Studio, DBeaver or HeidiSQL

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed it was the problem, I was using a sql user to connect with the database, once I changed it to windows authentification it helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encounter is a Python-specific error related to string literals.

In Python, the backslash `\` is an escape character in strings. When you have the sequence `\U` in a Python string, it expects a Unicode escape sequence to follow, which is why you're seeing the error message about a truncated `\UXXXXXXXX` escape.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={user};PWD={password}')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''
   BULK INSERT Namen 
   FROM r'C:\Users\pllmkd\Desktop\test.txt'
   WITH (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
''')
c.commit()

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Or you could use a double backslash `\\` for every single backslash in your path

```
FROM 'C:\\Users\\pllmkd\\Desktop\\test.txt'
```

Comment: You didn't add the prefix to the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for all answers but I have akready tried your suggestions and they do not work.
This string is specified in sql query not with python so if I did that sql query crashes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use raw string literal for your file path, add r prefix before the single quote :

```
FROM r'C:\Users\pllmkd\Desktop\test.txt'
```

It prevent backslash character readed as an escape char.

Answer (score -1):

"C:/Users/pllmkd/Desktop/test.txt" format normally works in window and Linux both
so you can construct your query using f-string format like this

```
file_name = 'C:/Users/pllmkd/Desktop/ test.txt'


c.execute(f'''
             BULK INSERT Namen 
             FROM {file_name}
            WITH (
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
         ''')
```

or you can use

```
file_name = r'C:/Users/pllmkd/Desktop/test.txt'


c.execute(f'''
              BULK INSERT Namen 
             FROM {file_name}
             WITH (
              FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
         ''')
```